# How to mark band of duplicates in alternating colours?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In MS Excel it is very easy to highlight the duplicates, but how to highlight the duplicates alternately using two different colours? Like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an "easy" way to do this, but with formulas and conditional formatting, it's possible.

If your data starts in A1, then place a `1` in `B1` and then in `B2` use the following formula and copy down:

```
=IF(NOT(A2=A1), MOD(B1+1, 2), B1)
```

This should give you alternating `1` and `0` for each distinct grouping of rows:

[image]

Now you can just set your conditional formatting to be green on `1` and pink/red on `0` for column `B`.